# Edit Text - Focus on Touch

Tags: java, android, xml

I have created a note app.
In my app when i create a new note. By default, the cursor is at title edit text but I want to have a feature that if I touch anywhere on the screen the cursor should go to the description edit text. I have kept the description edit text in a separate linear layout which has a weight of 1.
Kindly find the images to get an idea.
In the given picture the area covered with the blue line I want to touch anywhere in that area and my focus should be directed to edit text where I have written the hint description

```
XML
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/scview"
    android:layout_weight="1">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/body_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:hint="Description"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"/>.

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Kindly find the image below:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=15zCQXmzH5W0AwptVynTrgKu_iJHCX4cV

Comment: this link u have shared above needs permission to view content

Answer (score 0):

Use `onClickListener()` on parent layout of your xml like this

```
 RelativeLayout parentRelativelayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewByRid(R.id.your_parent_layout_in_xml);
EditText edtDescription=(Edittext)findViewByRid(R.id.body_content);

parentRelativelayoutsetOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           edtDescription.requestFocus();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do i have to do any changes in xml as well

Comment: No, just give id of the parent Layout and use it

Comment: then where ever  u click on your parent layour cursur start blink in your description Editext

Comment: LinearLayout parentRelativelayout;
        parentRelativelayout=view.findViewById(R.id.scview);

        parentRelativelayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText editText=view.findViewById(R.id.body_content);
                editText.setSelection(0);
//here 0 is index where u want to cursur blink
            }
        });

Comment: make your parent layout clickable in xml
android:clickable="True"

Comment: used editText.requestFocus(); instead of setSelection

Answer (score 0):

You need to override dispatchTouchEvent method and changes focus , as user touch screen , dispatchTouchEvent method will be fired.

```
@override Boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev )  {
        Toast.makeText(context ,"dispatchTouchEvent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
    }
```